# Создание html таблицы

Tags: html, table

Я очень долго мучался и не понимаю как сделать такую таблицу : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основу таблицы я сделал без проблем :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><==!Table!==></title>
</head>
<body>
<table align = "center" width="900" height = "900"border = "2">
<tr>
<th style="background-color: green"></th>
<th colspan="4" rowspan="2" style="background-color: red"></th>
<th style="background-color: green"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th width="200"style="background-color: green"></th>
<th width="200"style="background-color: green"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th rowspan="3" style="background-color: red" colspan="3"></th>
<th style="background-color: green"></th>
<th style="background-color: blue" width="20"></th>
<th style="background-color: blue" width="20"></th>
</tr>
<tr>

<th width="200" style="background-color: green"></th>
<th style="background-color: blue" width="0"></th>
<th style="background-color: blue" width="20"></th>
</tr>
<tr><th width="200" style="background-color: green"></th>
<th width="200" style="background-color: green"></th>
<th width="200" style="background-color: green"></th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Получилась такая таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не понимаю как сделать синие квадраты и нижний большой красный куб.Помогите её пожалуйста закончить , если можно с объяснением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось так:

```html
<style>
 table {width: 400px;}
 td.green {background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
 td.red {background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px;}
 td.blue {background-color: blue; width: 50px; height: 50px;}
</style>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="green">1</td>
  <td class="red" rowspan="2" colspan="2">1</td>
  <td class="green" colspan="2">1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="green">1</td>
  <td class="green" colspan="2">1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="red" rowspan="3" colspan="2">1</td>
  <td class="green" rowspan="2">1</td>
  <td class="blue">2</td>
  <td class="blue">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="blue">2</td>
  <td class="blue">2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="green">2</td>
  <td class="green" rowspan="1" colspan="2">2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное ! Можешь объяснить , чем отличается th от td , и когда надо брать тэг td , а не th?

Comment: @True-hacker http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tipy-tegov/tegi-dlya-tablits

Comment: Насколько я помню, th - указывается для заголовочных полей, для остальной таблицы - td. Не отличаются ничем, насколько я знаю. Давно уже использую только td